# Pandas: Remove null values from multiple columns less verbosely

Tags: python, pandas, null

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({ 'X': [1, 2, 3],
                      'Y': [4, 5, 6],
                      'A1': [1, None, 3],
                      'A2': [4, 5, 6],
                      'A3': ['Not', 'being', 'used'],
                      'A4': [None, 3, 3, None] })

_ = plt.figure()
_ = plt.hist([ data['A1'][pd.notnull(data['A1'])],
               data['A2'][pd.notnull(data['A2'])],
               data['A4'][pd.notnull(data['A4'])] ],
             label=['A1', 'A2', 'A4'])
_ = plt.legend()
_ = plt.show()
```

Is there some way I can reduce the repetition and verbosity in the first argument of `plt.hist`, where I'm repeatedly calling `pd.notnull(data['A1|2|3'])` to remove the `None` values in the dataset?

**Edit:** It seems that there is being emphasis placed on the plotting, but I just used that for the sake of example - I actually want to learn how to better handle these data frames.

Comment: Is this what you want: `data.filter(like='A').plot.hist()`?

Comment: Using `data[['A1', 'A2', 'A4']].plot.hist()` will place the bars atop each other (editing example such to cause this issue), whereas in the example above (directly using matplotlib) the bars are side by side, which is necessary in this case. Is there a way to use `data[['A1', 'A2', 'A4']].plot.hist()` whilst placing the bars side by side? Also, I'd like to actually know how to more effectively remove those null values for cases other than just this one, so help with that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html) which seems omit `None`s:

```
#specify columns for plot
cols = ['A1','A2','A4']
data[cols].plot.hist()
```

[image: graph]

EDIT:

There is problem need working with columns separately, so one possible solution is `list comprehension` with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
cols = ['A1','A2','A4']
a = [data[x].dropna() for x in cols]
_ = plt.figure()
_ = plt.hist(a,label=cols)
_ = plt.legend()
_ = plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Please see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [258]: data.filter(like='A').plot.hist()
Out[258]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x10e280b8>
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
In [266]: data.filter(like='A').plot.hist(width=0.5)
Out[266]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x11f7b518>
```

Result:

[image]

You may want to read [great Pandas visualization docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#histograms)

Comment: Please see my comment on the question.